# Find the constant k so that f(x) is a pdf of the continuous random variable x. $\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }F(x)=\frac{k}{1+x^{2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, statistics

> Find the constant $k$ so that $f(x)$ is a PDF of the continuous random variable $x$. 
>   $$
>   \int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }F(x)=\frac{k}{1+x^{2}}\;\mathrm{d}x
> $$

Any help is appreciated in solving this.

Comment: Note: $f$ is not the same as $F$, and $k$ is not the same as $K$.  If you want people to help, please take the trouble to write your question carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: $$\int \frac{1}{1+x^2} = \arctan x + C$$

Hint 2: if $f$ is a PDF, then $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx = 1$$

Comment: @ChanC, that's a standard one from calc 1,  $\frac{d}{dx}\arctan(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$, so by the fundamental theorem of calculus...